# Laravel Validation: check why validator failed

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

If there a way to check whether or not the validator failed specifically because of the `unique` rule?

```
$rules = array(
            'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'postal_code' => 'required|alpha_num',
        );

        $messages = array(
            'required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
            'email' => 'The :attribute field is required',
            'alpha_num' => 'The :attribute field must only be letters and numbers (no spaces)'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
```

In laymans terms, I basically want to know: "did the validation fail because the email_address was not unique?"

Comment: Maybe provide an input which passes the other validation rules? (And checking the error messages).

Comment: But you can see exactly what inputs I'm checking for ... `email_address` and `postal_code`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check for a specific rule within the returned array of failed rules

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

    $failedRules = $validator->failed();

    if(isset($failedRules['email_address']['Unique'])) {

    ...
```

Comment: Converted to json, it seems to return `{"email_address":{"Unique":["users","email"]}}`

Comment: updated. You have to check against it by field, each field having its own array of rules.

Comment: Almost, but it's still always returning false, even though I can see that it's true.

Comment: Updated, the rule `Unique` is a key, so `in_array` didn't work :) so instead I used `isset`

Answer (score 1):

This will display an error and tell you what failed:

**Controller**

```
if($validation->fails()){

   return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
}

foreach($errors->all() as $error) {
  echo $error;
}
```

And in your blade template add this:

```
   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>
           {{$error}}
        </div>
   @endforeach
```

And that will return a message with whatever the error is. Email doesn't match. Field is required. Blah blah

You can also remove that email array from the $message. The validator will handle all that for you. You only want to use that if you want custom messages.

You can also try to var_dump this statement:

var_dump($validation->errors()); die;

Comment: Yes, but I need to know what failed within my controller, before getting to the view.

Comment: Well in your controller you can use that same foreach and it will display in your controller. I edited my answer so you can see

Comment: $errors->all() produces `Call to a member function all() on a non-object`

Comment: Sorry, yeah that won't work because it's supposed to redirect back to your previous page anyways. I will update the answer.

Comment: Check my answer you may just be able to var dump the results using var_dump($validation->errors()); die;