# Laravel - getting the validation error

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel, is there any way to know which rule was invalid. For example:

```
'email': 'email|max:20'
```

And let's assume that I want to know is the email max rule failed

Comment: you can customize your validation message, so that you can set custom message for email `max`. More details available in this blog http://cubettech.com/blog/how-to-create-user-registration-form-in-laravel How to customize validation message?

Comment: I don't want to change the message, I want to know what exact rule was broken 'email.max'

Comment: did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573617/laravel-validation-check-why-validator-failed#answer-25574649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get error message considering specific field, then mention the name of the Validation object `key` on `messages` array. [Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

> If validation has failed, you may retrieve the error messages from the validator.

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    $messages = $validator->messages();    
}

echo  $messages;
```

> You may also access an array of the failed validation rules, without messages. To do so, use the failed method:

```
$failed = $validator->failed();
```

> Retrieving All Error Messages For A Field

```
foreach ($messages->get('email') as $message)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: I don't want the message I want the key, mail.max for example.

Comment: Yes I did, I am getting the messages but not the rule that failing

Comment: What is the purpose of getting `rule`?

Comment: echo  $messages outside of the condition

Answer (score 0):

By default all validation errors will be flashed to the session and available through $errors array in the template. Every failed rule will generate a separate error.

Example of displaying the errors using Bootstrap classes, taken from the documentation. Place this somewhere in your Blade template:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

See more details in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages)

Comment: The error will contain the rule message but not the failed rule. Like: 'mail.max'

Comment: Yes, because normally end user doesn't need to know the rule name. But you can 1) change default messages and include the rule name eg. $messages = [ 'email.required' => 'email.required']; 2) extend Validator class and add this functionality properly. It all depends on your requirements (which are not disclosed in the question)

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you want to see rule names instead of proper error messages in the output array, just override Validator's addError() method, for example: protected function addError($attribute, $rule, $parameters)    { $this->messages->add($attribute, $attribute.'.'.$rule); }

Comment: I don't want to override the message. The thing I want to do is to do different logic when the max rule was violated and other logic when the email rule was violated.

Comment: You can't do this without extending Validator class, I'm afraid. The beauty of Laravel - it's easy to add your own extensions. A dirty way without extending would be - make custom error messages as I suggested earlier, then later on parse $error array and react differently on different messages. You would be able to trigger something special for your email rule violation. But it's not a nice way to do things, it's more of a hack/workaround

Comment: Yeah. It's bad news. I thing this pretty needed thing. Maybe I open an issue in the Laravel repo. Thanks @Denis

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is better to use custom validation message for email `max`. I assume you are doing like this

```
$data = 'data_to_validate';
$rule  = array('email': 'email|max:20') ;
$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);
```

Add custom validation for email `max` like this

`$message = array('email.max' => 'Exceeded max. email length');`

new validator

`$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule,$message);`

Now if `$validator->fails()` for email `max` then `$validator->messages()` will show your custom validation. This way you can know your `max` rule failed.

Comment: This is an overhead, it would be nice to get it with the built in validation s